# Can I use ALL or ANY to find minimum value in SQL?

Tags: sql, any

Example of Table :

Table name : Ex1

```
Number
2
5
6
7
1
5
10
```

How to find the minimum value by using ALL or ANY in SQL ?

Comment: use `min` - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_min.asp

Comment: Why do you want to use `ALL` or `ANY`?

Comment: @Sergio are you aware of [W3Fools.com website](http://w3fools.com/)(?

Comment: @mkk, no I just picked up the first content that explained the min function. In this specific case the site seems ok. Thanks for the link, I will see that in deep, later :)

Comment: @mkk - are you aware that the link provided by @Sergio shows a correct example of the function `MIN` ?

Comment: there were times when every answer, which contained link to w3schools got downvoted :) in that case probably it might be ok, it doesn't matter. People should know that they should not trust everything they find there. If someone does not know the MIN function most likely he is not very experienced, so he should be aware that there are better resources he can use to learn. Oh and to be clear, I was one of the first who upvoted Sergio's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must rewrite your question describing a little bit more your answer, if possible in which database you would like to do this.

I don't know why would you like to do that instead of using MIN function.

In Oracle you could do this

```
select * from ex1 where number <= ANY (select number from ex1 where rownum=1 order by number asc)
```

But this will have the same result as:

```
 select * from ex1 where rownum=1 order by number asc
```

You could also do this:

```
select * from ex1 where number <= ALL (select number from ex1)
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/AllAnySomeComparisonConditionsInSQL.php).

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of upsetting my SQL server instance by using ANY (ALL would be better),

```
select number 
from ex1 
where number not in 
    (select number from ex1 where number > any (select number from ex1))
```

I feel dirty now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ALL`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Ex1 
 WHERE Number <= ALL ( SELECT Number FROM Ex1 AS T2 );
```

Using `ANY`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Ex1 
 WHERE NOT Number > ANY ( SELECT Number FROM Ex1 AS T2 );
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using ANY/ALL instead of MIN/MAX?  (besides that it cannot be used with WHERE)

Comment: @skan: I used `ALL` and `ANY` in my answer because that is what was specified in he question! But to answer _your_ question: I think the words `ALL` and `ANY` are more expressive than their `MIN\MAX` equivalents, if you consider (and I do) that a SQL statement should tell the optimizer what you want rather than how to do it. That said, I also think the `(operator) ANY|ALL (table expression)` syntax is clunky and ultimately not the most expressive syntax available...

Comment: Aside: the fact you can express exactly the same things in many different may in SQL (while watching for null gotachas) is not a desirable feature in language design.